# content assist in phtml files not working in eclipse helios pdt

Tags: eclipse-pdt, content-assist, eclipse-3.6

I got a problem with my content assist of html attributes in Eclipse Helios.

When I do something like

```
<div style="|"></div>
```

and hit ctrl+space, normally the content assist for the style attribute appears. This works fine for *.html and *.shtml files.
But as soon as I rename the file to phtml, the content assist just fails and says no completion available.
Anybody got the same trouble and solved it?

I don't really know if this is an eclipse or pdt or whatever problem, but its really annoying.

Comment: I have the same problem too. This happen in php and html files too. Eclipse Galileo haven't this bug. Its a regression.

Comment: the bug report is inserted by me for pdt. Hopefully they release a new version soon

Comment: same problem here. whats the bug report link? i'd like to follow it

Comment: the bug was marked as closed right after creation. Cause it has been fixed by QS whatever this means. 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=320783

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in current PDT Release in Helios.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when I used a Galileo workspace with Helios. 
I solved the PDT autocomplete issue by deleting the following file:

```
<your workspace name>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.dltk.ui.prefs
```

And restart helios.

I found the solution on the [zend forum](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=6317).